# Merge PHP Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have multiple `arrays` and i'm trying to `merge` them. Imagine the following code;

```
$arr1[ 'a' ] = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
$arr2[ 'a' ] = array( 'd', 'e', 'f' );
$arr3[ 'a' ] = array( 'g', 'h', 'i' );

$arr1[ 'b' ] = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
$arr2[ 'b' ] = array( 'd', 'e', 'f' );
$arr3[ 'b' ] = array( 'g', 'h', 'i' );

$buf = array_merge( $arr1, $arr2, $arr3 );
print_r( $buf );
```

The result i'm expecting is;

```
Array
(
  [a] => Array
    (
      [ 0 ] => a
      [ 1 ] => b
      [ 2 ] => c
      [ 3 ] => d
      [ 4 ] => e
      [ 5 ] => f
      [ 6 ] => g
      [ 7 ] => h
      [ 8 ] => i
    )

  [b] => Array
    (
      [ 0 ] => a
      [ 1 ] => b
      [ 2 ] => c
      [ 3 ] => d
      [ 4 ] => e
      [ 5 ] => f
      [ 6 ] => g
      [ 7 ] => h
      [ 8 ] => i
    )
)
```

I tried using `array_merge( )` and `array_combine( )` without success. Hope any one can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

`$buf = array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this :

```
<?php
$arr1[ 'a' ] = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
$arr2[ 'a' ] = array( 'd', 'e', 'f' );
$arr3[ 'a' ] = array( 'g', 'h', 'i' );

$arr1[ 'b' ] = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
$arr2[ 'b' ] = array( 'd', 'e', 'f' );
$arr3[ 'b' ] = array( 'g', 'h', 'i' );

$array = [
    'a' => array_merge($arr1['a'], $arr2['a'], $arr3['a']),
    'b' => array_merge($arr1['b'], $arr2['b'], $arr3['b'])
];

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it won't scale at all - you'll need to keep adding levels to your `$array` each time a key is added, or create a loop to do it. PHP's [built in functions](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive) will almost always win over custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

`array_merge()` only looks one level deep into arrays. You should use [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) for [this](https://eval.in/189450):

```
$buf = array_merge_recursive( $arr1, $arr2, $arr3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

$arr1[ 'a' ] = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );

$arr2[ 'a' ] = array( 'd', 'e', 'f' );

$arr3[ 'a' ] = array( 'g', 'h', 'i' );

$arr1[ 'b' ] = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );

$arr2[ 'b' ] = array( 'd', 'e', 'f' );

$arr3[ 'b' ] = array( 'g', 'h', 'i' );

$array = array(

```
'a' => array_merge($arr1['a'], $arr2['a'], $arr3['a']),
'b' => array_merge($arr1['b'], $arr2['b'], $arr3['b'])
```

);

print_r($array);

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25704359/2812842), which was posted 30 minutes ago